# Can't access action.payload of ActionCreator created using Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-observable, redux-toolkit

I can't seem to access the payload of an action created using RTK slice in a redux-observable pipe. I wonder if redux-observable is designed to work together with RTK at all, and whether I should switch to typesafe-actions instead.

```
export const signUrlsEpic = (action$: Observable<Action>): Observable<Action> =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(actions.getPresignedUrls),
    exhaustMap((action.payload) => // <- Here: Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'Action<any>'
      from(api.getPresignedUrls(action.arguments)).pipe(
        map((response) => {
          console.log(response)
          return actions.setPresignedUrls(response)
        })
      )
    )
  )
```

The action is exported from the slice.actions. I tried to cast the action as ActionCreatorWithPayload but it didn't help.

Comment: Not sure if it's correct syntax for code which you provide. Try to use
`exhaustMap(({payload}) =>`

Comment: There's no syntax error in VSCode other than that at the action.payload line. I get similar error by changing that to {payload}: Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'Action<any>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the error was quite obvious! The reason the payload was not available was because I declared the type to be `Observable<Action>`. It should've been declared `Observable<PayloadAction>`.